# Domain user directory being created as /home/username@domain instead of /home/username

Tags: linux, active-directory, sssd, amazon-linux, realm

I am using an amazon linux 2023 box and i joined the instance to domain using `realmd`.

The issue is that when i try to login with my AD credentials, the user directory is being created as `/home/username@domain` instead of `/home/username`.

Here is my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file:

```
[sssd]
domains = avengers.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
default_domain_suffix = AVENGERS.local

[domain/avengers.local]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = AVENGERS.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = avengers.local
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad
ad_gpo_access_control = disabled
```

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
```

to

```
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
```